# adding data to complicated mysql join/view

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I am hoping someone has experience with this type of situation I am having.

I have mysql database of users, with there data across multiple tables.

I am using a tool on my local machine to query this information and then check users into an event based on an id number.

going forward I will reference the above by "database" and "local" respectively.

I can query the database and get the data I need with a complicated set of inner-joins. To aid in this I created a view, which works great.

My local can read this view compiled data without a problem.

Now here is my problem. The local would like to modify data in this dataset. The two fields it wants to modify doesn't currently exist. The local tool cannot create new entries only update/modify existing ones.

Now, I don't think I can do what I want with the view I created. I'm thinking I need to create a new table that holds all of this combined data including the two new fields so that it can modify them as needed. This would be easy if it was a one time sync but of course that isn't the case.

I need to regularly view the combined data and update my new table with it. I would only need to update 1 field in each row (true/false) and then add any additional rows. Ideally I would like to remove deleted rows but that may prove to be more difficult.

As for updating the field of my new static table I think I would set each row's field to false then query all rows that have the field set to true and update those records in the static table to true.

As for adding new entries to the table, I figure I would query all records, look at the row that has the highest unique identifier and then do another query to select all rows that have a higher uid.

As for removal of rows, I don't have a clue.

Am I totally off base and making this way more complicated then it needs to be or is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Custom join for reference:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.fullname AS name, usr.id, usr.username, 
usr.firstname, usr.lastname, usr.email
FROM app_course AS c
INNER JOIN app_context AS cx ON c.id = cx.instanceid
INNER JOIN app_role_assignments AS ra ON cx.id = ra.contextid
INNER JOIN app_role AS r ON ra.roleid = r.id
INNER JOIN app_user AS usr ON ra.userid = usr.id
INNER JOIN app_user_enrolments AS enr ON usr.id = enr.userid
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want. How can you "modify data in this dataset" if the fields you want to modify don't exist? Could you show examples of what you're trying to do?

Comment: generally speaking, views are read-only. only in very specific circumstances could you update a view and have that change propagate to the underlying tables.

Comment: I have a feeling that _triggers_ is the feature you need to look at. They allow you to configure actions that take place whenever a table is modified.

Comment: I was afraid I wasn't being very clear. Because views are read only and I don't see a way I can associate data to the view, I will create a new table with all of the existing fields/data plus the two new ones needed. The local application will then be able to modify the fields in the new table, I just need to figure out a way to keep the data up to date in my new table. I only need 1 field kept up to date plus add/rem of new records. We are only talking about a few 1000 records so i'm not to worried about performance. I will only run it once or twice a day. Do _triggers_ work with joined data?

Comment: Barmar, it appears _Triggers" are my answer. If you post it as an answer I can up-tick/mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per @Barmar in the comments above Triggers are the answer.